# How to restore or recover a Logical Drive (RAID 5) on HP Proliant DL380 G6 (Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard)?

Tags: raid, drive

I have shutdown the server to replace one failed SCSI HDD (Port 2i: Box 1 : Bay 7) running on RAID 5. The rebuilding for the RAID was completed successfully. However, I noticed the Logical Local Drive F is still not accessible (as per Picture 1).

Please advise how I could recover the Logical Local Drive F ? Thank you.

[Picture of Server Drive Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrRph.png)

[Picture of Smart Array Controller Enclosure Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXnNx.png)

Comment: Hi, please add a picture of diskmgr, to know what disk is f:

Answer (score 3):

You can try to run chkdsk and it is better to have backups always available if you are dealing with Raid 5 on HDD.